# keep git files in another folder

Tags: git

How can I set up git to keep track of files in folder `~/a` , but store the `.git` folder in folder `~/b`?

Also, to take this one (huge) step further, can I keep the `.git` folder on another server and run `git` commands from server `a` to check `git st` for example, on server `b`?

Basically, i'd like to to able to use git on a certain folder without keeping the `.git` directory in that same *folder*. and for my second question above, i'd like to take that one step further by not even keeping the `.git` directory on the same *server*

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable.

In bash:

```
export GIT_DIR=~/b
```

or, in PowerShell:

```
Set-Item env:GIT_DIR $env:HOME\b
```

Alternatively you can use the `--git-dir` command line parameter on all `git` commands:

```
git --gir-dir=~/b status
```

See [this article about git environment variables](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/04/11/environment.html)

About putting the Git repository directory on another server: well, as long as you have mounted the file system from that server and have appropriate permissions, that should work fine. The git commands that operate on your local directory care mostly about accessing the file system, so they work as long as that works.

(To clarify: Above I am assuming that `~/b` *is* the git directory, if `.git` is a subdirectory of `~/b`, you should use `~/b/.git` instead)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way: you can specify real path of `.git` folder in a file, and redirect operations to it.

For example, create **a text file** `A/.git` and fill it with

```
gitdir: B/.git                # assume B is a non-bare repo
```

Then you can have a work tree in A, which uses `.git` folder in B.

BTW This is also how `git submodule` works.