# Can git track files in another folder

Tags: linux, windows, git

I am new to git and I keep all my git repos in one folder inside an NTFS disk so that both Windows and Linux partitions can see it. The problem is that executable files in that folder can't be given execution permissions in Linux.

For the repos that contain executable files, I've been working in a directory of the Linux partition, so that I can execute them, and then once I'm done editing them, I copy them back to the relevant repo folder to keep version-controlling them.

---

**Side note (for GolezTrol):** 
*When I say executables, I mean, for example, `*.cpp` or `*.java` files. If I want to compile those on an NTFS partition, I will get an error if I try to run the executable. So I can't work in the NTFS folder, I have to work in the Linux partition. Think for example, the workspace folder in Eclipse. I can't make any app work if I place it in the NTFS folder. So I have to move it to the Linux partition, edit my files, and then copy the relevant files back to the repo folder in the NTFS partition. I'm not tracking the executables, I'm tracking the files that produce those executables. I hope this clears it up.*

---

I was wondering if there is a way to keep the version-control of those files in their repo folder, while the files live in the Linux partition, so that I don't have to copy them back when I'm finished editing, and I can still see them from Windows. Something like a link to the executables folder that lives in the repos folder, maybe (it would probably be nice to be able to edit them from Windows too, as if they really lived in the repo folder, but I guess that won't be possible).

I searched SO and found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391904/keep-git-files-in-another-folder). I tried the first answer, although it's not exactly what I'm aiming for, but it didn't work for me. I placed the `.git` file in my executables folder, containing:

```
gitdir: path/to/repo/in/NTFS/disk/.git
```

and then initialized the repo, but I got an error:

```
$ git init
fatal: Not a git repository: path/to/repo/in/NTFS/disk/.git
```

So I went back to the repo folder (in the NTFS disk), did `git init` and came back to the executables folder. Now I get a different error:

```
$ git init
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: path/to/executables/folder
```

I think I didn't understand the answer.

Regarding the second answer, I couldn't understand how to implement it either.

So, wrapping up, my question is... **how can I have the executable files in a folder in the Linux partition but version control them from the repo folder in the NTFS disk? Would it be possible to make Windows see those files?**

P.S. I would like to avoid (if possible) getting into mounting or editing fstab files.

P.S2. This question is different to the one I linked. I'm thinking more of a sort of link to the executables folder from the repo folder. It would be ideal to see the files from Windows too. If that is not possible, I'm open to other answers, since the answers in the linked question didn't work for me. Had those answers solved my problem, I wouldn't be asking this question.

---

## Update:

My executables directory:

```
$ tree -L 1 -aF --dirsfirst
.
├── file.txt
└── .git

0 directories, 2 files
```

- Contents of file.txt: `file`
- Contents of .git: `gitdir: /media/admin/DATA/github/af-62/.git`

My NTFS directory (that is, `/media/admin/DATA/github/af-62`):

```
$ tree -L 1 -aF --dirsfirst
.
├── .git/
├── .gitignore
└── LICENSE.md

1 directory, 2 files
```

(Please don't pay too much attention to the files, they're placeholder files for now.)

The `-a` option shows hidden files, as those whose name starts with a dot, and the `--dirsfirst` shows directories first, so in the first case, `.git` is at the end while in the second `.git` is at the beginning.

In the NTFS directory:

```
$ git log
commit f8f7e3bac01f51e5d819a31e28c1a42c181b0407
Author: private <user@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 15 11:50:44 2015 +0200

    First commit.

$ git checkout /path/to/executables/folder/file.txt
fatal: /path/to/executables/folder/file.txt: '/path/to/executables/folder/file.txt' is outside repository
```

In the executables directory:

```
$ git init
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: /path/to/executables/folder/.git

$ git checkout file.txt
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git

$ git checkout /media/admin/DATA/github/af-62/LICENSE.md
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git
```

According to jvdm's [linked resource](http://www.cirosantilli.com/git-tutorial/#gitfile), "[...the `.git` file...] *It must point to a valid Git bare repository*", but `/media/admin/DATA/github/af-62/` is a valid repository, isn't it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't put executables in git in the first place.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have edited my question, please take a look now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [keep git files in another folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391904/keep-git-files-in-another-folder)

Comment: A completely different approach you might consider: some build systems support out-of-tree builds, meaning you could put your source files and `.git` directory together on your shared NTFS volume, but still generate your executables elsewhere.

Comment: @hvd That's true, but those don't pose a problem :-) The problem is when you can not do that.

Comment: You *can* always do that. It's just that if it involves completely rewriting the existing build system, it might not be worth the effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell git that `/path/to/executables/folder` is the working
dir of the git repository `/path/to/repo/in/NTFS/disk/.git`, one way
to do it:

```
cd /path/to/executables/folder
echo gitdir: /path/to/repo/in/NTFS/disk/.git > .git
```

Now notice that a git status (if `/path/to/executables/folder` was
empty) will show all your files as deleted.  Then you can:

```
git checkout .
```

To checkout them into your working dir.

Comment: Notice I prepended `/` to the relative paths since it doesn't make much sense if not, and I don't know how they related to each other to give a proper example. BTW, I think this question should be marked a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391904/keep-git-files-in-another-folder).

Comment: A git status tells me `fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git`. If I do git status in /path/to/repo/in/NTFS/disk/, it just sees what's in that folder (doesn't see the files in the executables folder)

Comment: Please, verify the contents of `/path/to/executables/folder/.git` -- it should have `gitdir: /path/to/repo/in/NTFS/disk/.git` (or whatever is the path to your NTFS partition). FYI, in essence you are getting two working directories for the same repo from this setup: to exchange files between them, you need to `checkout` the files from a commit. Untracked file in one working dir necessarily won't appear in the other working dir, by definition.

Comment: Contents of .git: `gitdir: /media/admin/DATA/github/af-62/.git`. This is my NTFS folder. I tried `git checkout /path/to/executables/folder/file.txt` and I get `fatal: /path/to/executables/folder/file.txt is outside repository`. If I do it the other way around, I get `fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git`. I think it's because it's a file and it wants `.git` to be a folder?

Comment: By default git uses its [current working directory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) to determine its [working directory](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States). That's why your `git checkout` failed, so `cd /path/to/executables/folder`. Ensure it is pointing to a [valid git repository](http://www.cirosantilli.com/git-tutorial/#gitfile).

Comment: I've updated my question, could you please take a look?