# How to add another directory to git repo in Pycharm?

Tags: git, pycharm

I've got git repo in such directory: `~/python/projects/project_name/`.
I need to add another directory like: `~/airflow/` to be tracked by git.

Pycharm solution would be preferable as I use git via Pycharm but every help will be appreciated. How should I do it?

Comment: Should `~/airflow` be in home strictly or can you copy it to your project dir?

Comment: The problem is it should be in home as other apps use it. I'm trying to resolve it but I didn't find solution yet. Maybe I just should open another repo for `~/airflow`?

Comment: That's one possibility yes. But it also depends on what you mean by "other apps use it". Do they use only one executable, do they read from it and write to it? Another possibility is to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391904/keep-git-files-in-another-folder)

Comment: Thanks @mnestorov. I mean it's doable to move this directory but I'd prefer to leave it as it is. I'll check out your suggestion.